# Average cost of SpaceWalk

Tags: iss, eva, cost

How much does it costs NASA for an astronaut to perform a single spacewalk? Not including salary just the cost of actually sending someone into space.

Comment: Also, you should consider that this more specific question is still unanswered: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14119/cost-of-an-eva-on-the-iss

Comment: I think in this day and age it makes sense to have these be a single question. Thus, I'm going to merge the two.